# Xamarin Forms ConverterParameter XAML error Invalid Property Path Syntax

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I have a text binding in my XAML as follows:

```
Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColumnToCaption}, ConverterParameter=-1}"
```

It simply takes the column number and looks up what the caption should be for that column based on data I have stored in a collection.  That has been working fine but after one of the last set of upgrades to Visual Studio / Xamarin forms, the XAML intelisense started generating the error "Invalid Property Value".  I didn't think much of it because the app seemed to work. Then some weird things started happing in my app and I noticed in my error list, I have a 43 "Invalid Property Value" errors listed (basically one for every place I use the ConverterParameter).

I double checked the MS documentation to ensure nothing changed (this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) and it still shows passing the value in as a number is OK.  Here is the example from the MS documentation:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Red, Converter={StaticResource doubleToInt}, ConverterParameter=255,
     StringFormat='Red = {0:X2}'}" />
```

I am simply trying to rule this out as the source of my problem but I cannot seem to find out how to get the error to go away.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

OH here is the converter code just so you can see it:

```
public class ColumnToCaption : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string ls_ReturnValue = ""; 
        try
        {
            if (System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter.ToString()) < 0)
            {
                if (App.gvm_AppSettings.AutoExpire)
                {
                    ls_ReturnValue = AppResources.Time;
                }
                else
                {
                    ls_ReturnValue = AppResources.CheckedIn;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ls_ReturnValue = App.gvm_AppSettings.FormFieldCaptionText(Int32.Parse(parameter.ToString()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            App.ProcessException(ex);
        }

        return ls_ReturnValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you still run the app? When you create a new app with the same xaml, do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes the app still runs but weird things are happening and I am trying to resolve these errors to ensure they are not the root of the problem.  I have not tried a new project as I am trying to get this one out the door

Comment: If the app still runs means the code is correct, i am not sure what cause these errors. The normal way is to delete the bin and obj to clean and rebuild.

Comment: OK I will try that.  Thanks

Comment: I deleted the bin and obj files and it made no difference.

Comment: I am not sure what cause this issue. But if you could run the app well, forget that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not add a string resource?

```
...
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:DoubleToInt x:Key="doubleToInt" />
        <x:String x:Key="twoFiveFive">255</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
...
    <Label Text="{Binding Red, Converter={StaticResource doubleToInt}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource twoFiveFive}}" .../>
...
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: This would require me to create a string resource for every single parameter I want to use.  (In my case there are many).  That seems like a lot of extra work for something that should simply be fixed.  However, if this ever does become a blocking problem for me, I will keep this solution in mind as it should work.  Thanks @Sorcamshadow.